# Android how to draw Linear layout corners shape like this

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to make a layout corners with shape like in this images .i goggled in net but i didn't found any code regarding curve shape, please help me ,please check the below image.
i want to design linear layout with curve shape.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/curve"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Hi, This layout has rounded corner borders ..." />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#a9c5ac" >
    </solid>

    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#1c1b20" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"    >
    </padding>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="-15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="-15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="-15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="-15dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: use background as a image with transparent...

Comment: i want to draw this using <shape> in android?

Comment: Please post what you have done to achieve this first..

Comment: best way is use 9.png drawables. In xml it's not possible.

Comment: can you show me with any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/curve"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Hi, This layout has rounded corner borders ..." />
```

use this curve.9.png image

[image]